# How to set disk size for a virtualbox vm in Chef's Test Kitchen

Tags: chef-infra, virtualbox, test-kitchen

Pretty much what the title says: I need Kitchen to tell VirtualBox that the VM's hard drive should be 500gb.  I've scoured the docs and not found anything (kitchen.ci).

Am I just not looking in the right places?

Comment: I think you are using vagrant to launch virtualbox. So here is the docs: https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant

Comment: frustation - looks like this is inside VirtualBox itself.  The base image I started with was built to 40GB and its too old to increase the size.  So it looks like I have to create a fresh base image using the new VirtualBox format that can be resized.

Answer (score 0):

the disk size is given by the box that you are using. though, you can override it using [`vagrant-disksize`](https://github.com/sprotheroe/vagrant-disksize).

1. install `vagrant-disksize` plugin for vagrant

   ```sh
   vagrant plugin install vagrant-disksize
   ```
2. create a `Vagrantfile` that looks like the following

   ```rb
   Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
     config.vagrant.plugins = ['vagrant-disksize']
     config.disksize.size = '50GB'
   end
   ```
3. add the `Vagrantfil` to the `vagrantfiles` in the [driver configuration in `.kitchen.yaml`](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant#-vagrantfiles)

   ```yaml
   ---
   driver:
     vagrantfiles:
       - Vagrantfile
   ```